# Strapi deployed on Google App Engine not able to see images just uploaded with Strapi Provider for Google Storage

Tags: file-upload, google-cloud-storage, strapi

help !!! Im deploying strapi to GAE. Right now the issue is that I cannot see uploaded images... so Im using the provider recommended on the documentations for strapi: https://github.com/Lith/strapi-provider-upload-google-cloud-storage/blob/master/README.md, nevertheless, although I can upload images and review that they were correctly uploaded by going to the cloud store interface and actually see the images up there, I cannot access them. I have granted both Storage Admin and Storage Object Admin to the account service, also created keys for it, but still unable to get the images I just uploaded... getting 403 error... Does anybody has experience with this situation?

this is my plugins.js file:

`module.exports = { upload: { provider: 'google-cloud-storage', providerOptions: { bucketName: 'strapi-sqlite-post.appspot.com', publicFiles: false, uniform: false, basePath: '' }, } }`

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following the official documentation of Strapi:

[Google App Engine Strapi](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/deployment/google-app-engine.html)

In this guide you are going to:

```
1.Create a new Strapi project
2.Configure PostgreSQL for the production enviroment
3.Deploy the app to Google App Engine
4.Add the Google Cloud Storage file uploading plugin by @Lith
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked that yet, but probably you should change

`publicFiles: false` to `publicFiles: true` ?

Answer (score 0):

Even with public set to true I was having this issue, so I set the whole bucket public. This is fine if you ONLY intend to add media that you intend to be viewable to the public to your strapi media library.

You can do this by navigating to your bucket in the GCS console.Go to Permissions > add. In the NewMembers field type "allUsers" and in the Role select Google Storage > Storage Object Viewer.